# GWT RPC failure

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, rpc

I'm trying to build a war of my GWT app using the ant ...

but I'm getting exception as

```
Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String org.cellbeans.client.InfrastructureService.getAllEmails()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
```

and

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/swapnil/tomcat7/webapps/Infrastructure/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-user.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Please help on this issue...

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` is usually a classpath issue. You're missing the Hibernate jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what your problem is. I'd need more information. I'll take a stab at it though. Here are 2 common mistakes.

You need to make sure that the library you are using is located in `web/WEB-INF/lib` where `web` is the folder within your `webapps` folder in Tomcat.

You also need to add the following line in your module `.gwt.xml` file.

```xml
 <inherits name='name.of.your.package' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the hibernate jar which contains the org.hibernate.Session class to your (tomcat?) server classpath. You can also remove the gwt-user.jar from the classpath, you only need the gwt-servlet.jar in the server classpath.